# How to resize activity listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

Hi I want to resize my listview in android.

I have other source than previous topics.

.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentDirectoryTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Current directory:" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

.class

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

How to resize my list? It is always small. Same after changing textSize.

This is whole class ListFileActivity.

```
public class ListFileActivity extends ListActivity {

private String path;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Use the current directory
    path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + AppConstant.DIRECTORY;
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    }
    updateCurrentDirectoryTextView();

    // Read all files sorted into the values-array
    List values = new ArrayList();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.canRead()) {
        setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
    }
    String[] list = dir.list();
    if (list != null) {
        for (String file : list) {
            if (!file.startsWith(".")) {
                values.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(values);

    // Put the data into the list

 /*   ListView lst = new ListView(this);
    //String[] arr = {"Item 1","Item 2"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mylist,values);
    lst.setAdapter(ad);*/

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

private void updateCurrentDirectoryTextView() {
    ((TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentDirectoryTextView))
            .setText("Current directory: " + path);
}
```

}

Comment: Is it in a `ScrollView`?

Comment: Check the answer [ListItem layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item)

Comment: i suggest you make each row of your listview large. so the entire list view will become large. do this by making a xml layout for each row in your listview. if you dont know how to do that add comment.

Comment: Try to create your custom adapter for this check my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406362/list-item-view-in-a-relativelayout/24406950#24406950

Comment: @AbhinavRaja i think that you understood what I want. So what I have to do is the new xml? I know how to make new, but I dont know how to connect it with other sources...

Comment: All you need is to find out how to custom a list view. when customizing listview, you have chance to custom view of each row in listview by getView() method. There is a lot of article about it on internet, please do by your self. After you got something, we are easy to help you.

Comment: were you able to do it or still stuck with it?

Comment: i do it other... I absolutely remake it... because nothing was good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the weight, i.e. remove this line

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Also what you are trying to do by setting a text size to listView? you should do it with adapter or individual item layouts

Comment: it doesnt work for me...
I want to resize list view i want that every row will be higher

Comment: Then just specify different layout for list item [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item) You can set font-size then padding or margin so your list items will be bigger

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Is responsible for setting the adapter for every list element.

What determines the size is the list element layout that is inflated by the adapter, not the ListView itself. In your case, that is android.R.id.text1, which is defined by the system. Therefore, if you want to change it, you need to create your own adapter. This is from an example:

```
public class MyDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyData>
{
    MyDatadata[] = null;

    public MyDataAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, MyData[] data)
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public MyDataAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<MyData> data)
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.data = data.toArray(new MyData[data.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        MyDataHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new MyDataHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.mydata_1);
            holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.mydata_2);
            holder.txtTitle3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.mydata_3);
            holder.txtTitle4 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.mydata_4);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (MyDataHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        MyData mydata= data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(mydata.getName());
        holder.txtTitle2.setText(mydata.getType());
        holder.txtTitle3.setText(mydata.getDate());     
        holder.txtTitle4.setText(mydata.getStatus());

        return row;
    }

    static class MyDataHolder
    {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtTitle2;
        TextView txtTitle3;
        TextView txtTitle4;
    }

    @Override
    public MyData getItem(int position)
    {
        return data[position];
    }
```

The item xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mydata_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#736F6E"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/mydata_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/mydata_1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#736F6E"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         />
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mydata_3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/mydata_2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#736F6E"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         />
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mydata_4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/mydata_3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#736F6E"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And use it like this:

```
     ArrayAdapter<MyData> adapter = new MyDataAdapter(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.listelement_mydata, mydatas);
     setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Later I needed to change this to a SimpleCursorAdapter though because of changes in stuff, which looked like this:

```
    Cursor c = getMyDataDataSource().getMyDatasCursor();
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(inflater.getContext(),
            R.layout.listelement_mydata, c, new String[] { "name", "type", "date", "status" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.mydata_1, R.id.mydata_2, R.id.mydata_3, R.id.mydata_4 }, 0);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But you needed an ArrayAdapter so that's the one you will need.

EDIT:

....this might have been a stupidly bloated answer, considering you can probably use a single-textview List Element XML in place of android.R.id.text1, without your own adapter.
I won't remove it because if you need anything more complicated than a single textview then it might come in handy, but... yeah. Just define a single element XML for the list view with a single text view in it and it should work.